# Help Following guide

Tags: magento2, php, blocks

I'm trying to integrate Google Address to magento, following [this guide](https://webkul.com/blog/integrate-autocomplete-google-address-magento-2/)

But I dont understand a line in php, here's the block definition:

```
namespace Webkul\Autofill\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Autofillform extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

/**
 * @param Context $context,
 * @param array   $data = []
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Return ajax url for button.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGoogleApiKey()
{
    return trim($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('autofill/general_settings/google_api_key'));;
}

}
```

But in the function getGoogleApiKey I don't understand where _scopeConfig comes from, Is not been set on the __construct function.

Is this guide correct or there's something missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Take a look at this class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Template.php I have looked at it, there's nothing there.